# Retrieve multiple model values from radio button asp.net c# mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor table generated from my Customer model. I put a radio-button into this table for the user to select which customer they want, then I have an action bar at the top of this table, I'm looking to be able to retrieve both the Customer ID and CustomerFirstName field by using this one radio-button. Is this possible with jQuery or C#? Right now I have the radio-button getting the Customer's ID but not the name. If I get the unique customer name field then I can just use jQuery AJAX post to pass these two fields to my controller. Any ideas?

Here is the radio-button html:

```
`<input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="selectedCustomer" value="@item.ID" />`
```

also have this field:

```
`<input type="hidden" id="hdnCustomerID" />`
```

then for some of my action bar actions like Edit:

```
    `<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "0" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get" }, 
     new { @class ="openDialog", data_dialog_id = "aboutlDialog", 
     data_dialog_title = "Edit", id = "btnEditCustomerID" })</li>`
```

the jQuery function that changes as a radio-button is selected:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val($(this).val());
```

but that only requires the customer ID, I want to create a link that gets the ID and FirstName field.

Comment: okay sorry about that, I can add anything else you think you need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just used a ajax to get a string from my controller:

jQuery:

```
var CustomerID = jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val();
        var CustomerName = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Customer/GetCustomerName',
            data: { id: CustomerID },
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                CustomerName = data
            }
        });
```

controller method:

```
public string GetCustomerName(int id)
    {
        Customer CustomerObj = _customer.GetCustomer(id);
        string customerName = CustomerObj.FirstName + " " + CustomerObj.LastName;
        return customerName;
    }
```